# Accessing a Entity Refererenced field of the current node

Tags: 8, nodes

I have to render a field of a node that is inside a content type in Drupal 8.

I have a content type called `summary` that has a field, called `field_content` that is an Entity reference field for unlimited items of a specific content type (article)

I'm able to get the current node and handle the `field_content`, but I cant access each of referenced items  inside  of this type.

Also I have tried to debug the `field_content` with  kint but the browser crashes (I suppose that it happens becasue the data dump is very big) and I can't access the inner properties (I have to get a field called `field_desc_text` inside each article).

I need the node or the nid to load it  of each of this inner items.

This is what i've tried:

```
       $currentNode = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    foreach ($currentNode->get('field_content') as $nodeRef)
    {
      kint($nodeRef); //*This debugs the entire referenced node, but there is no sight of my desired fields
      die;
     // kint($nodeRef[0]); *Cannot use object of type Drupal\\Core\\Field\\Plugin\\Field\\FieldType\\EntityReferenceItem as array
     // kint($nodeRef->get('title')); *Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Property title is unknown."

     die;

    }
```

And this is the output of the kint($currentNode):

https://mega.nz/#!Fogx0LpC!CYvc6YSRs1ZcgOAc4RCfDo5iVqjBLYckvuFEUgqRGx8

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `kint but the browser crashes`, you need to lower your max level [follow this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224928/how-to-make-use-of-devel-debugging-functions-on-large-or-complex-objects#224931)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the entities referenced by an entity reference field using the following code.

```php
$currentNode = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$entities = $currentNode->get('field_content')->referencedEntities();
```

The value returned from `referencedEntities()` is an array of objects that implement [`EntityInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/interface/EntityInterface/9.3.x).
See the documentation and the code used by [`EntityReferenceFieldItemList::referencedEntities()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21EntityReferenceFieldItemList.php/function/EntityReferenceFieldItemList%3A%3AreferencedEntities/9.3.x) for more details.