# Can kint be used to debug templates?

Tags: 8, commerce, debugging

Normally, I can use `kint()` in the place of `dump()` to debug my twig templates.  [The theming manual agrees.](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates)

However, this doesn't work for me in Commerce 2.

In `commerce-product.html.twig`, I added

`{{ kint(product) }}`

And rebuilt the cache.

This caused me to be redirected to the "install" url, with the message "Drupal is already installed".

If I use `{{ dump(product) }}`, I get the expected output, but this array is enormous and hard to read so I want to use kint.  Is there something different about variables in Commerce?

If I use `{{ kint(links) }}` and the like in a template copied from core I see the kint output correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make use of Devel debugging functions on large or complex objects](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224928/how-to-make-use-of-devel-debugging-functions-on-large-or-complex-objects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object/array is too big for your server resources to handle the default kint settings.

Edit **modules/devel/kint/kint/config.default.php** and set `$_kintSettings['maxLevels']` to a lower number to reduce recursion and the memory needed for dumping variables. The default is 7, I have mine set to 4. If 4 still doesn't work for you, keep lowering the number.

Answer (score 3):

For debug big array, i use first :

```
{{kint($array|keys)}}
```

after i got key i can kint the array with the key.
With this method i don’t have memory error.