# What's wrong with this simple debugging code?

Tags: debugging

Spend whole day trying to make working simple debugging code for [Tweme](https://www.drupal.org/project/tweme) theme (using D8).

```
function tweme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {   
   $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
   kint($node);
   kim ($variables);
}
```

The only response is blank page no other info.

What's wrong with my debugging code?

Comment: If you got blank page, you should check the PHP error log to see any details about your problem. Maybe one of the debug functions doesn't exist, or the function is already defined.

Comment: Have no php log access ... Just wonder if it's memory issue. Once I left the browser for longer time I was able to navigate the values. Once in a day ...

Comment: Would be good if you can setup your local environment to test it, otherwise it's blind coding. Try using `var_dump($variables);` instead plus `die()` if it's test server. Maybe your `$node` object is too big to render and you've got out of memory error. But without access to error log it's just a guessing. You need to provide more information about the problem or at least clarify which line exactly causing the blank page.

Comment: How are you going to debug without the error logs? You should use xdebug for this because I can tell you right off the bat that using kint or any of the functions in Devel are going to crash your browser 99% of the time, and this will wind up taking you ten times the amount of hours to deduce and work with.

Comment: I would expect the Devel module to display variables using Kint and Ksm functions as advertised (not so strange ...). If it's not possible will look for other solution but that's all I have found for the day long. Will try xdebug. Could be will have to move locally as well. PHP memory limits on the server could be a point ...

Comment: Have moved ahead by adding test like `if (!empty($variables['elements']['#node']))`.  The kint table is shown now but then error message is displayed Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by ... /webs/drupal8/modules/devel/kint/kint/Kint.class.php" at line 263.

Comment: Use a php debugger that lets you step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `kint()` and `ksm()` functions output the results in the status messages block.

Make sure in */admin/structure/block* the **Status messages** system block is set to a region.

Comment: Yes, it is. What's more I have got the result once I left the browser "blank" for number of minutes. The kint table was displayed but nothing else. But as I said, it was once per whole day, and browser seemed to be hanging.

Comment: @PaulPaku hmm all those are symptoms of the array being too big for your server resources to handle. Try my [answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250507/can-kint-be-used-to-debug-templates/250540#250540) it will probably fix your issue.

Comment: had the same idea.