# Find if $view object is a block or page

Tags: views, 8

I am unable to debug this because when I print the display object I get a memory error from the size.
so with something like this I can get the display title.

```
function mailnow_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  $displayObj = $view->getDisplay();
  $displayName = $displayObj->display['display_title'];
}
```

I can get the machine name with `$view->current_display == 'companies_page'`

But I want to be able to get the display type for instance "Block" or "Page"

Comment: `I get a memory error from the size` If you're using [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) Kint, you just need to [lower the recursion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/250540/27710)

Answer (score 3):

You can get it with

```
$plugin_id = $view->style_plugin->displayHandler->getPluginId();
```

Comment: For clarity, that is for the active display, not in the generic sense for all displays attached to a `$view`.  The active display isn't available in some of the early hooks (and I totally forget which ones).