# twig dump() creates WSOD error

Tags: debugging, wsod

this is my first Drupal installation (I'm a symfony dev) and I've spent several hours trying to get dump() working. However it just causes a WSOD.

Maybe related: I'm unable to install kint, there's issues with it now being a sub-module of devel and I haven't been able to install it.

Settings:

- Drupal version 8.9.1
- memory limit set to 6,000mb
- execution time set to 90 seconds
- Windows
- acquia dev desktop
- php 7.3.15
- Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.0h mod_fcgid/2.3.9

If anyone has suggestions I'm keen to hear it! Drupal is quite interesting from what I've seen so far. It's been a bit frustrating as someone new to Drupal, trying to get basic things working.

== Update ==

I have corrected a config error I made while configuring the site. [See here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vRAGMf_QQIfjGaxyDN1As5eepuDW-NqcS1Uvouu-Q86PDo0euDDruRCQgbqXewwS2LjWPNbioTjKyVH/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000#slide=id.p) (for correct config).

Calls to `dump()` (in twig) for null variables work, but `{{ dump(items) }}` will hang and then result in a 500 error (see link above).

Comment: How about enabling the error reporting rather than staring at a WSOD page? Add to /sites/default/settings.php `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` and you'll be able to see the actual error.

Comment: Also, to be able to dump stuff on twig, you need to [enable Twig Debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates).

Comment: **Update** is most likely due to this, [Twig dump crashes site/server with out of memory](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2647298). Use Kint instead and [lower the kint recursion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/250540/27710)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this.

In Drupal, modules also use composer (which I wasn't aware of). The vardumper module depends on the symfony/var-dumper package.

Running:

composer require --dev symfony/var-dumper

causes dependency conflicts, however using:

composer update

Will install the var-dumper package, fix the problem - now I can see very beautiful variable dumps.

Lesson learnt:

- Always check composer for dependency errors.

Comment: I've had a similar issue but I did it with composer update drupal/core ---with-dependencies (should install correct symfony/var-dumper unless you manually did it in composer.lock)