# Howto theme list of nodes as item-list?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to show a block with related nodes. The function `getRelatedArticles()` is a complex one and I can't build it with views. Is it possible to use the method `viewMultiple()` and output the list as item-list? If not, what would be the best practisce becide looping over the array and build the render array for each node? Something similar to the following code (which obviously does not work):

```
class RelatedArticleBlock  extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    $related_nids = $this->getRelatedArticles();

    $nodes = Node::loadMultiple($related_nids);
    $block['content'] = [
      '#theme' => 'item_list',
      '#list_type' => 'ul',
      '#wrapper_attributes' => [
        'class' => [
          'row',
        ],
      ],
      // I want to do something like:
      // '#items' => \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->viewMultiple($nodes, 'teaser'),
    ];

    // I would like to avoid the following, build each node on it's own.  
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $block['content']['#items'][] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->view($node, 'teaser');
    }

    return $block;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your reasoning behind not wanting to loop through and build each node? Curiosity on how to write cleaner code, or something else?

Comment: Yes, for performance reasons. I read `viewMultiple()` has a better performance than just `view()` ... but didn't dive into details.

Comment: I see that EntityViewBuilder::viewMultiple (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilder.php/function/EntityViewBuilder%3A%3AviewMultiple/8.5.x) exists, so it should work, Have you tried it and run into an error?

Answer (score 1):

`viewMultiple()` also optimizes the rendering process by returning a common #pre_render callback in the build array, see the discussions and linked topics here [Twig: "for" does not display variable content without first displaying all variable content](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267234/twig-for-does-not-display-variable-content-without-first-displaying-all-varia), so you can't put the output directly in `#items`.

So building each node on its own is the way to go and you probably won't find any differences in performance, because both methods result in the same caching mechanism.