# How can I theme a paragraph on admin edit pages?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm struggling to override the template on the admin interface for a content type. I'm going to need to do several modifications to the edit form to meet the editor's requirements, however, I seem to be unable to get this to override.

The page source gives me the following

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'paragraphs_summary' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'modules/contrib/paragraphs/templates/paragraphs-summary.html.twig' -->
```

If I make a change to the twig file specified I can make my change, however, it's not my module so I shouldn't be making changes and I only want to override on specific content types so I have to go for a theme based override (which of course is the right way to do it)

I've copied this twig template to

```
themes/custom/my_theme/templates/paragraph--my-content-type-paragraph-type--paragraphs-summary.html.twig
```

and quite a number of combinations of this, rebuilt the cache with `$ drupal cr` yet the admin interface still gives the default template instead of my one (and yes, I have remembered to set the admin theme as my new theme).

I want to be able to have a different presentation in the admin interface to that of the anonymous visitor's view, hence looking at overriding the templates.

Any suggestions of how I can achieve this?

Comment: Turn on [Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates). I can't see any of those template suggestions you mention on my local install. Have you tried `paragraph--PARAGRAPHTYPE--summary.html.twig` ? (without parent content type!)

Comment: I have twig debugging on

    twig.config: { debug: true, auto_reload: true, cache: true }

Any other settings that should be enabled? 

If I remove the parent content type, then won't that impact all content types, not just the one I need to change?

Comment: Yes, this does affect all content types. But paragraphs simply does not provide a theme suggestion based on the parent node. You either have code additional [theme suggestions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.2.x) or create a new display mode that is only used in this specific node (this can be done without custom coding)

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear, I'll look at a theme suggestion, I've written many bits of custom code already and suspect there will be many more needed on this project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add the paragraph parent field in the theme suggestions alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269895/how-to-add-the-paragraph-parent-field-in-the-theme-suggestions-alter)