# hook_preprocess_field() $variables crashing while printing

Tags: 8

I am trying to modify a file field value and add a download svg icon and then add it to a twig file by using a preprocess field.

```
function my_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_download') {
    print_r($variables);
  }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but the variable is not loading and it is timing out (memory exhaustion)

Comment: Objects in Drupal 8 often are massive, with rescursion, and can end up with the issue you are seeing. Dumping objects often does not work so well. You may want to look at the Devel module's kint(), as I think it may have come up with ways to work around this.

Comment: @Jaypan thanks for your quick answer. I have enabled it but still facing the same issue, is there a way to see what elements are present within variables without facing this issue

Comment: You need to use a real debugger. Kint/Devel + the browser simply cannot handle this.

Comment: @Kevin I have tried that and I am getting an error saying exception has occurred. This is the error :

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "entity.node.create" does not exist. on 201 of routeProvider.php in core/Drupal/Routing/RouteProvider.php

Comment: What does that have to do with printing a variable? I’m lost.

Comment: @Regokonda debuggers don’t produce errors like that, they just help you to debug the code. You’ll need to learn about and use XDebug or similar; as others have mentioned dumping vars in the browser isn’t going to work in a lot of cases

Comment: @Kevin "What does that have to do with printing a variable? I’m lost" 

True, I thought the same.  not sure what is causing this. I will try some of the below suggestions and see if I can find the root caus. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Clive the debugger works fine when I check other parts of the code. Will dig through this. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0):

Use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) with [vardumper](https://www.drupal.org/project/vardumper) and dump only the `$element` instead of the whole `$variables` something like:

```
function myfi_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_download') {
    // Dump only the element.
    dpm($element);
  }
}
```

Comment: On D8 better use the Devel sub-module Kint and then `ksm($element)`. And @see [How to make use of Devel debugging functions on large or complex objects](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/224931/15055).

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed devel module, you can enable kint module.
In your code you can use the `kint()` function to print the variable...

Example:

```
function myfi_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_download') {
        kint($variables);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are perfectly fine, but short of enabling development-specific modules, you can sometimes get by in the short term by only printing the keys of the array, rather than the entire array;

```
print_r(array_keys($variables));
```

After seeing what keys are available, you could then print_r() just the particular key that you're looking for within $variables to see what's in it.