# how to print node object in drupal 8

Tags: theming, nodes, debugging

in drupal 7 we could use `kpr()` from devel module or php `print_r()` and `var_dump()` functions to print $node object in node.tpl file or hook preprocess node in purpose of debugging and finding a field or ..

but in drupal 8 we can't use php functions in twig and I tried `kint()` and `dump()` to print node in twig but no success. ( I've already set `debug: true` in services.yml ) ( more detail: `kint(node)` in twig file makes an infinite loop and causes memory size exhausted in browser).

so the question is how to print node object in drupal 8 using twig or hook preprocess node?

more details:

I have custom twig template for article: node--article.html.twig and the content is like:

```
<article>

<div>
    {{ content.body|render }} {# this works #}
</div>

<footer>
    {{ kint(node.field_custom.value) }} {# prints the custom field value without any problem #}
    {{ kint(node) }} {# this causes infinite loop and memory issue #}
    {{ content }} {# prints all content fields without any problem #}
    {{ kint(content) }} {# nothing happen or display with this! #}
    {{ kint(label) }} {# infinite like node #}
</footer>
```

Comment: `in twig file makes an infinite loop and causes memory size exhausted in browser` to avoid this, [follow my answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/250540/27710)

Comment: @NoSssweat, there is a similar answer in the duplicate https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/224931/47547

Comment: @NoSssweat
thank you